# parent page title on sub menu

Tags: 8

I am building a website where i generate a submenu based on my main navigation.
The structure looks like this:

- Home
- About
- Work at

  - vacancies
- contact

when you land on one of the level 1 pages, a submenu will appear in the sidebar with the children links of this page.
i want the title of the parent page to show above this menu.

also, on the vacancies page there's a overview of vacancies, and when you go to one of the detailed vacancies i want it to show
"Work at" and not "vacancies" in the submenu title.

i've tried alot of things but can't find the right solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [menu_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module with the patch in https://www.drupal.org/node/2809699 should work.

**Note**: you'll have to select the "Use the following as title" field to "Active trail's parent title" when configuring your block.